# jQuery change event not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am using jQuery change event on a input text box. It seems to work properly in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11. 
Is there any other event similar to change which is supported in IE.

jQuery 1.7.

```
<body>
   <input id="search"></input>
</body>

$('#search').on('change',function(){
   alert('hii');
})
```

**jsfiddle**:--
https://jsfiddle.net/7v0ohes8/

Comment: Works for me. How are you testing this code?

Comment: i am running the fiddle in IE 11 and it does not seems to work. if i click enter after entering some data it does nothing

Comment: Your question says IE10. So I tested in IE10. Do you get any console error?

Comment: no, it does not throw any error.i checked it both IE 10 and 11

Comment: There is a **[bug reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/998355)** for this. You can try `input` or `keyup` or `blur` event as a workaround.

Comment: @ShaunakD I did it posted an answer already..

Comment: @pankajparkar, that is just a wrokaround. Change fires on `focusout` of the input. `keyup` will occur everytime key is pressed.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to bind event on `keyup` that would work

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
   alert('hii');
})
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7v0ohes8/6/)

Here is another [**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270535/2435473) of Same Answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is specific to certain version of ie11, mine is from MS virtualbox machine.
If change alone does not work, try this combo:

```
$('#search').on('change blur',function(){
   alert('hii');
})
```