# JavaScript in IE11 populating an input field from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onclick, internet-explorer-11

I have a calendar which is currently displaying in an iframe of a form created in a third party software to select the date. In chrome, Firefox and edge the behaviour of clicking the link in the date auto-fills the input field for 'date selected' on the parent page.

However in IE11, this doesn't happen. There's also nothing appearing as an error in the console on IE11 when I check that. The code for the link is as follows;

```
<a name="01/08/2018" id="date" onclick="myFuncclick(this.name);" href="javascript:myFuncclick(this.name)" target="_self">1</a>
```

with the following code to catch it at the bottom of the calendar page;

```
function myFuncclick(name){
    parent.myFuncread('#Field38',name);

}
```

and on the parent page the following script;

```
function myFuncread(field, value){
$(field).val(value).change();

}
```

Already I'd seen that there have been posts about JS onclick not playing nice with IE11, and had attemtped to remedy this by using the href="javascript:myFuncclick()" addition but IE11 still seems to be blissfully ignorant of the whole thing.

Has anyone had similar issues with IE11 & managed to work around it?

EDIT -

So in IE11 I can (by changing the function to have an alert line as well) get IE11 alerting the variable that Chrome and Edge are happy passing. For me this means that the parent window JavaScript might be where the error lies, maybe something in the way IE11 handles cross-window scripts.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: Does JSFiddle allow for the iFrame element of it? I can do if it does, but if it doesn't then I'm not sure there'd be much to gleam from it.

Additionally if the iframe source is not from the same site as the input box, most browsers will stop the passing from child window to parent window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery change not firing until blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270452/jquery-change-not-firing-until-blur)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values

The element in the script that catches the event uses object-values, which is unsupported in IE11.