# How to avoid triggering false function between change and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an `input` and a clear `button`. If the user type something in the input field and blur it, `change()` will be trigger and do something. But if I want to click clear `button` and trigger `click()`, `change()` will still be triggered. How do I solve this?

I tried this, but it doesn't work. `var clear` will never be true.

```
$("#inputid").change(function() {
  var clear = false;
   $("#clearbtn").click(function() {
     // if clear button is clicked, do something
     clear = true;
   });
   if (clear) {
     return;
   }

   // if clear button is not clicked, do something else
...
```

Comment: Why are you attaching a new event handler in the `change` event handler function?

Comment: @Satpal I am new to web development and not quite sure what to do to handle this. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Satpal If I put `click` outside of `change`, `change` will always be triggered, not `click`

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270535/1685196) `change()` seems to fire only after a `blur()`. And by clicking a button, you `blur` the input. So if you really want to track every keystroke, use `keyup()`

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve - not click to trigger click(), but what the user will see/do.  Why would the "clear" button stop the input? (as I read from your code this is what would happen)  This might be better with a tickbox

Comment: "change will still be triggered" - add some console.logs to all your event handlers and watch what's happening - `change` occurs *before* `click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is quite tricky
the problem is `onchange` event is called before the `clear button click` event is called
to overcome this you can introduce a timer in the onchange event so that it waits for user's immediate action
like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clear = false;
  var isTimerOn = false;
  function HandleChange(){
    if(clear){
     // if clear button is clicked, do something
     $("#inputid").val("");
    }else{
     // if clear button is not clicked, do something else
     alert("do something else");
    }
    clear = false;
    isTimerOn = false;
  }
  
    $("#inputid").change(function() {
    isTimerOn = true;
    setTimeout(HandleChange, 80);
  });
   
   $("#clearbtn").click(function() {
     clear = true;
     if(!isTimerOn){
        HandleChange();
     }
   });
});
```

here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6d9r1qsc/

Answer (score 1):

You should move the **click** event outside of the **change** event.

```
$("#clearbtn").click(function() {
  // if clear button is clicked, do something
  $("#inputid").val("");
});
```

Comment: Hi. Yes I tried this. But `change` will always be triggered, no matter I click clear `button` or somewhere else to blue the input

Comment: That is correct. You should check the value of "#inputid" at the beginning of the "change" event. if its not empty, then proceed with the rest of the function.

Comment: I made a quick fiddle for you: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gqad79s/)